# Android 'Back' button action

Tags: android

Can i assign the action of the default Android 'Back' button into another button? I mean without having to write the code, is there a predefined 'Back' method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

onClick of Button add `onBackPressed();`

```
public void onClick(){

  onBackPressed();

}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways for your purpose:

1st:
Override the `onBackPressed` method in your `Activty`:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

2nd: Override `onKeyDown` and look for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {

        }
        return false;
    }
```

If you want to combine both (lets say you want the backAction on the menuButton, It'll look like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        {
                onBackPressed();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is a detail, but if you handled event, you should return true.