# How to Go to previous Activity through back button by Skipping DialogFragment

Tags: android, back-button, android-navigation

When I click the back button It goes to previous action rather than Previous Activity

**what is want to do is this** : 1.Activity next-> 2.Activity2 next-> 3.DialogFragment(select user from DialogFragment) next-> Activity2 (with selected user) backPressed-> Activity.

**what i am at is** :
      1.Activity next-> 2.Activity2 next-> 3.DialogFragment(select user from DialogFragment) next-> Activity2 (with selected user) backPressed-> 5.DialogFragment backPressed->Activity

Scenario is:
When i open this Activity and selecting user from dialogFragment from OnClick Event as shown in below Image:

[image]

after selecting user screen is:

[image]

when i click the back button on Top right Corner it again opens the same fragment rather than opening previous activity..
I have Tried lot of ways but Could not find solution. 
Please Help.

[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5tff.png)

my code:

//

```
Back button in toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.o2htextOne));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_arrow);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.o2htextOne), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            Intent intent=new Intent();



        }
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
       {

            finish();

        }
      return true;

    }
```

Comment: do you dismiss your dialogFragment when moving to user detail activity??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 'Back' button action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342592/android-back-button-action)

Comment: I think you should just call `finish()` only and not to start new activity in `onOptionsItemSelected` and also as @sam_0829 said "dismiss".

Answer (score 2):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
upArrow.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(AgentCreateIntimation.this);
        }
});
```

try to use this in the place of

```
{
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   Intent intent = new Intent();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just check this condition in `onBackPressed` and do the action what ever you want:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (dialogObj != null && dialogObj.show()) {
      dialogObj.dismiss();   
   } else {
      //this.finish();
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```